# Scroll the Scrollview when textview content increases

Tags: android, scrollview

I take 5 relative layout for expand and collapse animation.When i click on one of the relative layout textview gets expanded.For last relative layout textview expanded but scrollview not set to bottom to up the textview content.we have to scroll to see textview content.i want when i click on relative layout text will automatically view by scroll the scrollview to bottom please give me suggestion.
HelpActivity.java

```
RelativeLayout mLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltRowOne);
    final TextView mLayoutToBeExpanded1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpContact);
    mLayoutToBeExpanded1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout()
                {
                    // gets called after layout has been done but before display
                    // so we can get the height then hide the view
                    h1 = mLayoutToBeExpanded1.getHeight();
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded1.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            }

        });



    RelativeLayout mLayout2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltRowTwo);
    final TextView mLayoutToBeExpanded2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpServiceContent);
    mLayoutToBeExpanded2.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout()
                {
                    // gets called after layout has been done but before display
                    // so we can get the height then hide the view

                    h2 = mLayoutToBeExpanded2.getHeight();
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded2.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });



    RelativeLayout mLayout3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltRowThree);
    final TextView mLayoutToBeExpanded3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpShareContact);
    mLayoutToBeExpanded3.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout()
                {
                    h3 = mLayoutToBeExpanded3.getHeight();
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded3.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded3.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                }

        });


    RelativeLayout mLayout4 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltRowFour);
    final TextView mLayoutToBeExpanded4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpPrint);
    mLayoutToBeExpanded4.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout()
                {
                    h4 = mLayoutToBeExpanded4.getHeight();
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded4.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded4.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                }

        });



    RelativeLayout mLayout5 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rltRowFive);
    final TextView mLayoutToBeExpanded5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpEmergency);
    mLayoutToBeExpanded5.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( 
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout()
                {
                    h5 = mLayoutToBeExpanded5.getHeight();
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded5.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    mLayoutToBeExpanded5.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                }
        });



    addAction(mLayout1, mLayoutToBeExpanded1, mLayoutToBeExpanded2,mLayoutToBeExpanded3,mLayoutToBeExpanded4,mLayoutToBeExpanded5);
    addAction(mLayout2, mLayoutToBeExpanded1, mLayoutToBeExpanded2,mLayoutToBeExpanded3,mLayoutToBeExpanded4,mLayoutToBeExpanded5);
    addAction(mLayout3, mLayoutToBeExpanded1, mLayoutToBeExpanded2,mLayoutToBeExpanded3,mLayoutToBeExpanded4,mLayoutToBeExpanded5);
    addAction(mLayout4, mLayoutToBeExpanded1, mLayoutToBeExpanded2,mLayoutToBeExpanded3,mLayoutToBeExpanded4,mLayoutToBeExpanded5);
    addAction(mLayout5, mLayoutToBeExpanded1, mLayoutToBeExpanded2,mLayoutToBeExpanded3,mLayoutToBeExpanded4,mLayoutToBeExpanded5);

}



public void addAction(final View layout, final View summary1,final View summary2,final View summary3,final View summary4,final View summary5)
{
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int lay_clicked=layout.getId();
            if(lay_clicked==R.id.rltRowOne)
            {

                if (summary1.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    expand(summary1,h1);
                }
                else
                collapse(summary1);

                collapse(summary2);
                collapse(summary3); 
                collapse(summary4);
                collapse(summary5);
            }

            else if(lay_clicked==R.id.rltRowTwo)
            {
                if (summary2.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    expand(summary2,h2);
                }
                else
                collapse(summary2);
                collapse(summary1);
                collapse(summary3);
                collapse(summary4);
                collapse(summary5);
            }

            else if(lay_clicked==R.id.rltRowThree)
            {
                if (summary3.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    expand(summary3,h3);
                }
                else
                collapse(summary3);
                collapse(summary1);
                collapse(summary2);
                collapse(summary4);
                collapse(summary5);
            }
            else if(lay_clicked==R.id.rltRowFour)
            {
                if (summary4.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    expand(summary4,h4);
                }
                else
                collapse(summary4);
                collapse(summary1);
                collapse(summary3);
                collapse(summary2);
                collapse(summary5);
            }
            else if(lay_clicked==R.id.rltRowFive)
            {
                if (summary5.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    expand(summary5,h5);
                    final ScrollView Scrbar=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollContainer);
                    Scrbar.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Scrbar.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                collapse(summary5);
                collapse(summary1);
                collapse(summary3);
                collapse(summary4);
                collapse(summary2);
            }
        }
    });


}

private void expand(View summary,int height) {
    // set Visible
    summary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1,
            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    summary.measure(widthSpec, 300);
    ValueAnimator mAnimator;
    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, height, summary);

    mAnimator.start();
}

private void collapse(final View summary) {
    int finalHeight = summary.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0, summary);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            // Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
            summary.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}

private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end, final View summary) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            // Update Height
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = summary.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            summary.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return animator;
}
```

helpactivity.xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lnrAction"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/colorscroll" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lnrAction"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="About Contact Diary"
            android:textColor="#0260C5"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/underlineOne"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/gray_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/helpContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/underlineOne"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/abtcon"
            android:textSize="16dp" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rltRowOne"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpContent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underlineTwo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contactImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/underlineTwo"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/contact_home_screen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contactTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactImg"
                android:text="Contact"
                android:textColor="#0260C5"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underlineFour"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contactImg"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/helpContact"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/underlineFour"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/contact"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rltRowTwo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rltRowOne" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underline1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contactServiceImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/service_contact_home_screen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serviceContactTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactServiceImg"
                android:text="Service Contacts"
                android:textColor="#0260C5"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underlineThree"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contactServiceImg"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/helpServiceContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/underlineThree"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/service"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rltRowThree"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rltRowTwo" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underline2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contactServiceImgw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/share_home_screen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shareContactTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactServiceImgw"
                android:text="Share"
                android:textColor="#0260C5"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underlineFive"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contactServiceImgw"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/helpShareContact"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/underlineFive"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/share"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rltRowFour"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rltRowThree" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underline3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contactPrint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/print_home_screen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/PrintTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactPrint"
                android:text="Print"
                android:textColor="#0260C5"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underlineSix"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contactPrint"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/helpPrint"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/underlineSix"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/print"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rltRowFive"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rltRowFour" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underline4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contactEmergency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/emergency_home_screen_red" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/PrintEmergency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactEmergency"
                android:text="Emergency"
                android:textColor="#0260C5"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/underlineSeven"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contactEmergency"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_1"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/helpEmergency"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/underlineSeven"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/emergency"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sheetal, always post some code, so others can know about your problem.

Comment: can you share the screenshot to make your issue more clear?

Comment: atleast provide some code or part of that.

Comment: why you don't just use **ExpandableList** instead of all this codes? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Answer (score 0):

in your textView(or his relative layout) **onClickListner()** (or in your **onAnimationEnd()** ), you can call this method to scroll your scrollView to the bottom of the textView:

```
private final void scrollMyView(){
      yourScrollView.scrollTo(0, yourTextView.getBottom());
}
```

Comment: I want for last relative layout. when textview of last relative layout expanded scrollbar automatically moves down. I my demo code this will work but content of textview is not moving up